# diferencia entre el uso de funciones, vistas, triggers y procedimientos almacenados en sql server y mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Bueno espero hacer esto bien, es la primera vez que pregunto en este sitio.

¿Que son triggers, funciones, vistas y procedimientos almacenados ?
La verdad estoy empezando en esto de base de datos y tengo muchas dudas en el uso de las funciones, vistas, trigger y P.A desde la función de cada uno de ellos y sus diferencias ya que algunos se parecen mucho en sus estructura y desearía saber cuando debería usar cada uno de ellos, en que problemas es necesario por ejemplo mejor un trigger que un P.A o una vista que un trigger y cuando no.
¿Cuando usar cada uno de ellos en un problema?

Bueno espero no sea una pregunta de mucha molestia o muy tonta, de antemano les doy las gracias por contestarme.

Comment: Hola, la verdad es que si bien haz formulado dudas validas, estas son muy amplias y no son adecuadas para el sitio. Te invito a realizar el [tour] y revises [ask]. En particular deberías preguntar cosas puntuales *despues* de investigar por tu cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Te comento por ejemplo un **PA(Procedimiento Almacenado)**, guardará en tu interior una secuencia de una o varias sentencias SQL, de las cuales posteriormente podrás obtener utilidad y bastará que solo invoques el PA por su nombre, como te muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

**Nota aclaratoria: Los ejemplos que te mostraré son para MySQL pero asumo que la lógica y grado de funcionalidad deben ser muy similares a en SQL Server**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE datos()
BEGIN
   SELECT usuarios.*, categorias.* FROM usuarios
JOIN categorias
ON  usuarios.id_categoria = categorias.id
WHERE usuarios.id_categoria = 1;
END $$
```

Como puedes notar en la siguiente línea invoco dicho PA solo con call y el nombre de el mismo.

```
call datos();
```

Por otro lado las **vistas o views** por ejemplo se almacenan en servidor entonces eso ayuda a la carga de trabajo, una vista es una representación de los datos pero no implica acceso directo a los mismos y por último en un PA puedes pasar parametros que serán usados dentro de  tu consulta SQL, pero en las vistas no ya que solo son una representación estática de los datos

//EJEMPLO

```
--Aquí creo la vista y le asigno un nombre y con AS le indico la lógica SQL que tednrá que ejecutar
CREATE VIEW 
users_posts AS 
SELECT users.id,name, status 
FROM users 
JOIN posts 
ON users.id = posts.id_user;

--Para poder hacer uso de la vista la meto en una instrucción SQL regular y al final paso el nombre de dicha vista
SELECT * FROM users_posts;
```

Los triggers son usados para almacenar consultas y determinar en que momento serán estas mismas ejecutadas, la sintáxis es:

```
CREATE TRIGGER nombre_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
   ON nombre_tabla FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   --El código que será ejecutado por el trigger va aquí es decir las sentencias SQL
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día! Es un gusto poder apoyar en estas preguntas, ya que todos nos hacemos la misma pregunta en algún momento.

Views: Mas que nada son una representación basica de una o mas tablas, para lo cual puedes hacer Joins. Las hay dinámicas y estáticas; dinámicas, puedes realizar las funciones CRUD pero no es recomendable, y las estáticas solo es para realizar select y sus where. Utilizan mas espacio en memoria.
SP: Estos pueden tener funciones mas complejas que las vistas, y consumen menos espacio en memoria. Aceptan parámetros. Realizan las funciones CRUD.
Triggers: Estos solo actúan cuando tu le defines la acción para que se activen, pueden realizar las funciones CRUD. Prácticamente son como centinelas, si pasa esto... has esto.

Espero poder apoyar.